# Adding entries to layerlist context menu using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, layers, context-menu

I am implementing a Python based plugin for use with QGIS 1.8.

Most of it's user interface is contained within a QDockWidget but there are some layer specific controls I would like to append to the context menu displayed when the user right-clicks on the Table Of Contents.

Is there a way for me to manipulate this menu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applies to the current development version or the upcoming release 2.0.

You can use [QgsLegendInterface.addLegendLayerAction](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsLegendInterface.html#a423864ba68cb6c7045d41fa547e88838) for this purpose. This method lets you add new menu entries for a [LayerType](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#adf3b0b576d7812c4359ece2142170308) (VectorLayer, RasterLayer, PluginLayer)

```py
a = QAction( u"My Action", iface.legendInterface() )
iface.legendInterface().addLegendLayerAction( a, u"My Plugin Menu", u"id1", QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer, True )
```

If you set the allLayers parameter of addLegendLayerAction to False you can add the action only for specific layers. Given a variable *myLayer* pointing to a QgsMapLayer:

```py
aLyr = QAction( u"My Layer Action", iface.legendInterface() )
iface.legendInterface().addLegendLayerAction( aLyr, u"My Plugin Menu", u"id2", QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer, False )
iface.legendInterface().addLegendLayerActionForLayer( aLyr, myLayer )
```

You would then normally connect the QAction.triggered signal to a slot with the code you want to execute when your menu entry is clicked.

You should remove the action by calling the appropriate [removeLegendLayerAction](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsLegendInterface.html#abf79d765e164b143cf94978a51fb7d02) when your plugin is exiting.

```py
iface.legendInterface().removeLegendLayerAction( a )
iface.legendInterface().removeLegendLayerAction( aLyr )
```