# Adding an entry in contextmenu of QGIS Legend Layer Tree

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, layers, context-menu

Like this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/58860/13507) there was in QGIS 2 the possibility to extend the contextmenu of a layer from Python code.
Now I'm searching for this feature in QGIS 3. I'm looking for this in [`QgsLayerTreeNode`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Layer/QgsLayerTreeNode.html) class and its derived classes but couldn't find anything.

Does anybody know a way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at methods [`QgisInterface::addCustomActionForLayerType`](https://www.qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#a2e1394521d90f15fbddb0ce875520460) and [`QgisInterface::addCustomActionForLayer`](https://www.qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#afd2ba088d6a9ec9a7196d19c1b92c57a). The general concept of adding an entry to the context menu stayed fairly similar in QGIS 3. The methods have only been moved and renamed.

Simple example of adding an entry, which appears in the menu for all raster layers:

```py
a = QAction( u"My Raster Action")
a.triggered.connect(lambda: print('action triggered'))
iface.addCustomActionForLayerType(a, 'My Raster Menu', QgsMapLayerType.RasterLayer, True)
```

And just for reference, use [`QgisInterface::removeCustomActionForLayerType`](https://www.qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#ade0f6018f58a664c5acf713089bf16b4) to remove the menu entry.

Comment: Thanks, this works fine after I checked out that action 'a' has to be a global variable of 'self' in my plugin.